# logback pattern conversion from log4j to logback

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, logback

I'm trying to convert an xml configuration file from log4j to logback, this is my log4j code that have

```
<Property name="LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD">%xwEx</Property>
<Property name="LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN">yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS</Property>
<Property name="LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN">%highlight{%5level}{FATAL=white, ERROR=red, WARN=blue, INFO=black, DEBUG=green, TRACE=blue}</Property>
<Property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN">%clr{%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} ${sys:PID} --- [%t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}}</Property>
```

I dont understand the property `LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD`, what is `%xwEx` and what does it change on the pattern at the end, when I converted to logback, I didn't use it but I feel like I'm missing something.

**Edit:** saw what it means somewhere but dont know how to have the same thing with logback

xwEx – the throwable conversion word. The ExtendedWhitespaceThrowablePatternConverter adds additional whitespace around the stack trace